# How to programmatically align an Android TextView to the right of another TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

In the below code I have created two text views and added them programmatically to a relative layout.  I want to align them side by side.

The code runs fine but is not placing the new `TextView` to the right of previous `TextView` instead the new `TextView` is positioned at margin (0,0,0,0) i.e. upper right corner of the screen:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    relativeLayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_Layout);

    textView[0] = new TextView(this);//creates first textview
    textView[0].setId(0);
    textView[0].setText("1");
    textView[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape);//parses an image from shape.xml

    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    textView[0].setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);

    relativeLayout.addView(textView[0]);//creates another textview

    textView[1] = new TextView(this);

    textView[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams=
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT),(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));//create params for new textview

    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textView[0].getId());//to align the textview side by side
    textView[1].setText("2");

    relativeLayout.addView(textView[1], relativeLayoutParams);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Set the id of textView[0] to 1 instead of 0 (id needs to be a positive integer)
2. Add to the relativeLayoutParams of textView[1] a rule for RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP

The following worked for me:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams;       
TextView[] textView = new TextView[2];

// 1st TextView
textView[0] = new TextView(this);

relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

textView[0].setId(1); // changed id from 0 to 1
textView[0].setText("1");   

relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

relativeLayout.addView(textView[0], relativeLayoutParams);

// 2nd TextView
textView[1] = new TextView(this);

relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      

textView[1].setText("2");

relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
        textView[0].getId());
relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,
        textView[0].getId()); // added top alignment rule

relativeLayout.addView(textView[1], relativeLayoutParams);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: can you try to use a different id than 0 ?

Comment: Thanx Marc, it fixed the problem but do you know why can't we set the id to 0?

Comment: The javadoc says "Sets the identifier for this view. The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive number." Probably '0' equals no-id-set?