# Adding editText to customView

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I want to add EditText to canvas in specific coordinates.
Something like this :[image]

I tried to use code :

```
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);

        EditText textView = new EditText(context); 
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView.setText("Hello world");

        layout.addView(textView);

        layout.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        layout.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

        layout.draw(canvas);
```

But this EditText wasn't show keyboard on click. Can you help me?

Comment: can you specify who you have initialized canvas and its usage. Do you only want the edit-text with a line below ? as that simple task and need not take canvas implementation.

Comment: i need dinamically create different numbers of this view ( editText + text) , so i choose to create my custom View with this elements, to make future work more easily

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really need to draw it on a canvas...

Create a new canvaslayout.xml inside your res/layout folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="5" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Edit Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Change code too

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.layout.canvaslayout); 
//LinearLayout layout = youractivity.findViewById(R.layout.canvasLayout); 
layout.draw(canvas);
```

**Programmaticly:**

If you don't want to use XML (I don't see why not) you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238164/how-to-align-a-textview-to-the-right-of-another-text-view-programmatically-in-an) method. You change the linear layout to a relative layout and use something like this to put views to the right off another view.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams=
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT),(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));//create params for new textview

    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textView.getId());//to align the textview side by side
```

Comment: It's good idea , but i want to change coordinates of EditText in a different tasks. Sometimes i need to make : EditText + TextView ; Sometimes i need to make : TextView + EditText + TextView ; or TextView + EditText; so i can't use xml file , because i need always change coordinates of EditText

Comment: You can use different XML layout files for each possibility.

Comment: When i use xml files - it crashes in layout.draw(canvas); with NullPointerException :(