# Can't access a compoent after casting set.id() manually

Tags: android, android-layout, null

I have one little problem, can you guys help me.

I have a code like this:

```
TextView tz;
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setId(0x7f090024);
tv.setText("hello");
View vv = findViewById(0x7f090024);

if (vv != null)
{
    Log.e("number_id", "not null");
}
else
    Log.e("number_id", "null");

// also return error (java lang null pointer exception) with this
tz = (TextView) findViewById(0x7f090024);
Log.e("test", tz.getText().toString());
```

Why does this result always return `null` and I can't get a value from the second textfield `tz`?

Comment: check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)

Answer (score 0):

it returns null because `findViewById` refers to the `View` hierarchy built with `setContentView`. Your `TextView` does not belong to it, so you can not retrieve it with `findViewById`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can setID and you can access widget by getting id, but you need to check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238164/how-to-align-a-textview-to-the-right-of-another-text-view-programmatically-in-an) ,