# How can i display programmatically a textview next to a button in a RelativeLayout in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have created a `RelativeLayout` which contains a `Button` and a `TextView`. With this code, the `TextView` is displayed above the `Button`. What can i do, to align the `Button` left and the `TextView` right? What is missing?
This is my code:

```
    final RelativeLayout topRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    topRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
    mainLinearLayout.addView(topRelativeLayout);

    final Button restartButton = new Button(this);
    restartButton.setText(R.string.restartButton);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    restartButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
    restartButton.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    topRelativeLayout.addView(restartButton);

    final TextView timeTextView = new TextView(this);
    timeTextView.setText(R.string.timeTextView);
    timeTextView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    topRelativeLayout.addView(timeTextView);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you not do this in an XML? Is there a reason that you can't do this in XML and have to do it programatically?

Comment: Yes, i don't want to use `.XML` because in stead of one `TextView` as you see in this simple example, will be at least 45 and i don't want to write them manually. How can o align the `button` left and the `TextView` right?

Comment: Why would there be 45 TextViews? You can simply use "span" or have setText() set a longer character string

Comment: search SO before you post a question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12238482/1174987

Comment: As you see is not my case. I have created all dynamically. Colns Abt, gave me the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
button.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textviewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textviewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
textView.setLayoutParams(textviewParams);
```

Comment: Works perfecty! Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If this is really what you are trying to achieve you will need to set an ID for the button or TextView with the setID method on that view. Once that is done you can set the layout parameters for the other view to position relative to the button. Like this:

```
button.setId(1011);///OR WHATEVER INT YOU WANT
textView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height,left,top,right,bottomPadding,null,new int[][]{{RelatitiveLayout.ABOVE, button.getId()}});
```

To set the alignment of a view in a RelativeLayout use this:

```
button.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height,0,0,0,0,new int[]{RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT}));
```